# Specify --manifest-path while using cargo watch

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

A fantastic crate is [cargo watch](https://github.com/watchexec/cargo-watch), which allows, for example, for you to execute:

```bash
cargo watch -x run
```

to automatically rebuild/run on src change. This is amazing for development but one issue I have is that it seems to not support the `--manifest-path` argument that can be used with `cargo run` to explicitly specify the path to the `.toml` file of the project such that it can be run from a different pwd than the `Cargo.toml` file itself:

```bash
cargo run --manifest-path /home/user/project/Cargo.toml
```

The crate documentation doesn't mention anything about this, so I was wondering if anyone who uses this crate has found a way around this. When attempting to use the `--manifest-path` argument I receive:

```
error: Found argument '--manifest-path' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    cargo watch [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]
```

Which makes some sense as I know not all commands support the `--manifest-path` arg, but since the crate uses `cargo run` to run the project itself I'm guessing there is some way around this without using e.g. `sh -c 'cd [path to .toml file] && cargo watch -x run'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just use the invocation which lets you run arbitrary commands:

```bash
cargo watch -- cargo run --manifest-path=path/to/Cargo.toml
```